# Is it ok to use "module": "commonjs" in tsconfig.json for a Next.js project? Using ts-node to run scripts in a Next.js Typescript project

Tags: typescript, next.js, ts-node

This is the default `tsconfig.json` file that was generated automatically by `Next.js`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",            // <=== THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My problem with it is that I run some scripts across my project, and I use `ts-node` to run them.

I was getting all sorts of errors when trying to run scripts that had some imports on them.

For example:

```
import fs from "fs";
console.log("HERE");
```

I was getting: `Unexpected token export`

And I noticed that if make the following change to `tsconfig.json`

```
"module": "esnext",  // DELETE THIS LINE
"module": "commonjs" // ADD THIS LINE
```

Now the script runs fine.

**QUESTION**

I don't want to mess with the `tsconfig.json` that was auto generated by `Next.js`. Is it ok to make that change? Am I breaking or risking to break something? Should I create a different `tsconfig.json` file? What is the best option here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up choosing not to mess with `Next.js` default settings for the `tsconfig.json` file.

So I created a new config file that I've named `tsconfig_scripts.json`.

And it has basically the same content of `tsconfig.json`. I've just updated these parts:

**tsconfig_scripts.json**

```
"module": "commonjs",      // CHANGED TO THIS
"ts-node": {               // ADDED THIS
  "files": true
},
```

I've also added an npm script to call `ts-node` in an easier manner:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "ts-node-script": "ts-node --project tsconfig_scripts.json -r tsconfig-paths/register"
}
```

Notes:

- `--project tsconfig_scripts.json` sets the new custom config file
- `-r tsconfig-paths/register` allows you to use path aliases on script files

To use it, you just run this from the CLI:

```
npm run ts-node-script path/to/your/script.ts
```

Comment: tysm for this! feel like this should've been mentioned somewhere in official docs...

Answer (score 9):

Adding this `ts-node` field to my tsconfig.json worked!

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "include": [...],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Related ts-node documentation: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#via-tsconfigjson-recommended